# Socket timeout with mongo DB after 30 mins of inactivity

Tags: java, mongodb, azure, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

After 30 mins of inactivity or so I start getting the below error when I try to insert into mongo, When I try again it starts to work. Error Below. I'm on Azure:

```
[INFO ] 2018-09-10T12:00:43,188 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] connection - Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:26}] to XX.XX.XX.XX:27017 because there was a socket exception raised by this connection.
[ERROR] 2018-09-10T12:00:43,189 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] [dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Timeout while receiving message; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message] with root cause
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
        ava.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
t java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
```

Here is how I initialize my mongo Template:

```
@Bean
    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() {
        String[] addresses = mongoUri.split(",");
        List<ServerAddress> servers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String address : addresses) {
            String[] split = address.trim().split(":");
            servers.add(new ServerAddress(split[0].trim(), Integer.parseInt(split[1].trim())));
        }
        MongoClientOptions.Builder mongoOperations = MongoClientOptions.builder();
        mongoOperations.socketTimeout(1000 * 20); // I tried to increase the socket timeout to see if it helps but no help either
        mongoOperations.connectTimeout(1000 * 10);
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(servers, MongoCredential.createCredential(userName, dbName, password.toCharArray()), mongoOperations.build());
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient, dbName);
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate() {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    }
```

My mongod version is `3.6.4` and I'm using the same version of java driver.
I tried to increase/decrease the `tcp_keepalive_time` setting as provided in the docs using 
`sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=120` but no help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ohk. so we found that the `mongo java driver jar` was older than the mongo server we were using which was causing this issue. make sure that the driver supports the version of mongo server.